# Can we call WebService in locationManager didEnterRegion method when App is background? How to earn extra time to fulfill WS call?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, core-location, geofencing

I have set up one Geo Fence & monitoring using `startMonitoringForRegion` method. I am able to get events when Geo-fence region is entered & exited successfully. What i want to do is when i enter in certain geo-fence I want to make a Web Service call based on that location data & display Local Notification for Web Service Result [When App is in background / killed].

Will `beginBackgroundTaskWithName` method help?

In short:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
     // Make a Web Service Call to fetch data even 
     // **when App is killed/ in background mode.**
}
```

1. As per my knowledge when geo fence is breached app comes into
   background mode. Not sure for how long.
2. I can send Local Notification even app is killed/in background
   when geo fence is breached. Now what if i want to make web service
   call & display it's result as a notification when app is not in
   foreground.

What is the best approach to achieve this? Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your app can no way do anything when its in the background or killed, the app have to be active to do anything

Comment: Please check this. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-multitasking-background-tasks--mobile-6913

Comment: @Muneeba: This tutorial says WHEN APP GOES TO background then everything comes into the picture. It mentioned applicationDidEnterBackground method. I still don't get how it will help. Actually when Location Manager didEnterRegion method gets called app can be in background or even killed state. Can I initiate/make a call to Web Service in didEnterRegion when app is not in foreground?

Comment: "https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html" Please refer this.Specially "Background Fetch" section.you might get luck

Comment: You can make background mode on for your location updates so your  didEnterRegion will be called in background and for your custom task use background task identifier. If your app is killed you are out of luck then

Comment: @Muneeba Good one but as per my knowledge when we breaches pre defined geo-fence apple will launch app in background and then we can perform custom task but for small amount of time given by IOS.

Comment: Not in my knowledge, but thanks for info sharing. And i miss the push notification option in my comment in case when app is killed.

Answer (score 1):

Found very useful stuff that every app has some extra time that iOS offers to resolve certain unfinished business before the app goes into suspended mode. For iOS 7 the time has been reduced to around 180 secs (3 mins); earlier it was around 600 secs (10 minutes).

To earn extra time we need to initialize UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier

```
-(void) beginBackgroundUploadTask
{
    if(self.backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
    {
        [self endBackgroundUploadTask];
    }

    self.backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

        [self endBackgroundUploadTask];

    }];
}
```

Once the background task runs out of time from the stipulated allotted time, we should invalidate and end the background task.

```
-(void) endBackgroundUploadTask
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTask ];
    self. backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the methods like this

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"Region Datas %@", region);

    NSUserDefaults *userid = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *get_userid=[userid stringForKey:@"USERID"];
    [userid synchronize];
    NSLog(@"User Id %@",get_userid);

    NSString* urlStr1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.test.net/test.php"];
    NSLog(@"Enter Url %@",urlStr1);
    NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr1]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request1
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
         {
             NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
             NSLog(@"Success Result %@",result);
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Error Result %@",connectionError);
         }
     }];

}
```

Comment: How long it will support the request? Will above code work when app is killed? How long iOS make app awake in background when didEnterRegion is triggered?